# Копирование таблицы из базы данных в csv MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо копировать таблицу из базы данных MS SQL Server в csv файл

Использую команду

```
copy (select * from database table) to 'path'
```

но выдает ошибку

```
не удалось найти хранимую процедуру copy
```

простой запрос `select * from database table` выполняется верно

Comment: `mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name table_name> path`
Если хотите с условием по колонке:
`mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name table_name --where="someColumn='someValue'" > path`
[Пример](https://sysgears.com/notes/dump-a-specific-table-or-few-rows-mysql/)

Comment: а как это сделать в самом приложении MS SQL Server?

Comment: ```INSERT INTO OPENROWSET( {parameters} ) SELECT ...``` https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=INSERT+INTO+OPENROWSET PS. Copy - this is PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: [SQL Server Import and Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Pashok, а если подключение к субд было по учетной записи? то есть самого файла базы данных локально нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сам я с виндой не дружу, нашлось это:

```
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-EU2MTDD
       -Q "select * from Zoo.dbo.Zoo_Employees;"
       -o "C:\Users\Martyna\zoo_employees.csv"
       -W
       -w 1024
       -s ","
       -h-1
```

https://learnsql.com/blog/export-csv-file-ms-sql-server/